# load form from main class jdeveloper

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I would like to load the form `DataEntry` from the main class..  I'm a newbie to Java, any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame{

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataEntry dbJframe = new DataEntry();
    DbConnect connect = new DbConnect();
    connect.getData();
```

Comment: 1) *"..form DataEntry"*  What `DataEntry` form?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please *read* the helpful tag pop-ups before slapping them on your question.  This has ***nothing*** to do with HTML forms.

Comment: DataEntry is a Jframe form , i basically want it to load from Main class. thanks

Comment: *"DataEntry is a Jframe form"*  1) Again, a little louder this time.. ***For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).***  2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  The 2nd 'frame' should probably be a `JDialog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling

```
dbJframe.setVisible(true);
```

Seems that's what you need.